# Is x -> y the same in c as x.y in c#/java?

Tags: c, struct

Is `->` doing the same thing in C as `.` in Java/C#?

In Java/C# you access items inside a struct via the `.` operator.

It seems to me that `d_name` is inside `dir` and its being accessed as an item inside `dir`

```
DIR *d;
struct dirent *dir;
d = opendir("."); // get current directory
if (d)
{
    while ((dir = readdir(d)) != NULL)
    {
    // whilst item exists
    printf("%s\n", dir -> d_name);
    }
closedir(d);
}
```

If this is not the case then I am missing something and I would like a simple explanation if possible.

Comment: I'd hate to say it's the same, but it's similar in the sense that there is an *implicit* "dereference" that occurs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a vague sense, yes. Java does not have pointers, nor the concept of objects being passed by value; in essence, all objects are stored and passed by reference and the associated memory is freed by the garbage collector when unused.

Comment: Thanks, so it really is almost that simple, the `d_name` is inside that `dir` struct.

Comment: Close, but `dir` is a pointer to a struct that is dereferenced (followed) before the `d_name` member is fetched. `dir->d_name` is equivalent to `(*dir).d_name`.

Comment: Thanks, I need to do a lot more reading in *dereferencing* pointers to really understand. I still don't quite get the meaning of *dereference*. But your answer has cleared up whats going on in the above code so thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind the difference between an struct, and a pointer to an struct.

Let's assume a 32 bit compiler.

Let's create an struct:

```
struct point_i {
    int x; 
    int y; 
};
```

This struct has two int members. Each integer is four bytes in size so the struct size in total is eight bytes.

Then use the struct:

```
strut point_i my_point;        // 8 bytes allocated, lets assume that they  
                               // are located at address 0x10000000.
my_point.y = 10;
```

When you do this, the compiler knows where my_point is located and its size and it also knows where the member `y` is with respect to the struct. So it compiles (very roughly) to something like:

```
MOV [0x10000004], 10     ;; Notice that its 0x10000000 + 4. 
                         ;; The first four bytes are X so we skip them 
                         ;; to get to Y and put 10 in that memory address.
```

On the other hand, when you have a pointer:

```
strut point_i *another_point;       // 4 bytes allocated, the pointer size.
                                    // Let's assume in 0x20000000.

another_point = get_random_point(); // Get an address to some random point.

another_point->y = 10;              // You have to use -> to reference the member
                                    // because you are not dealing with an struct
                                    // anymore but a *pointer* to said struct.
```

And since the compiler has no idea what address you are going to put in that pointer it has to generate code that is a bit different.

```
MOV EBX, [0x20000000]     ;; 0x20000000 has your pointer. So we fetch it.
MOV [EBX+4], 10           ;; Dereference the pointer and put 10 in Y. 
                          ;; You can see that we now have two memory references, 
                          ;; one to get the pointer and another to get where it
                          ;; points to. So it is a layer of indirection.
```

Notice that this is a very simplified view of the world. The compiler/linker and the operating system resolve memory addresses on your programs. But it should clarify what's going on behind the courtains. Pointer dereferencing is a major part of C.

Comment: _Notice that this is a very simplified view of the world_ ...Really?  :)

Comment: Well, maybe not *so* simple :)

Answer (score 0):

Variables of class type in both .NET and Java hold references, whose behavior is similar to that of a malloc'ed pointer in C, except that C allows arithmetic and conversions between pointers and integers, whereas references allow no such arithmetic nor conversions.  If `o` holds a reference to an object of class C with a field `f`, `o.f` in C# or Java is roughly equivalent to `o->f` in C.

Instance methods take an implied parameter, which is guaranteed to hold a reference to an instance of the appropriate type.  If `im` is a non-virtual method of `o`, then `o.im(whatever)` is equivalent to `C_im(o, whatever);`.  If `vm` is a virtual member, the system will define an internal method which returns the address of the implementation applicable to a given instance.  Thus, `o.vm(whatever)` is equivalent to `C_get_vm(o)(o, whatever);`

Structures in C# behave more like structures in C.  Structure field access uses the same `.` token as class field access, but if `s` is a structure of type `S` with field `f`, then `s.f` in C# is like `s.f` in C.  Instance methods are called by passing a "byref" to the object instance, such that `s.im(whatever)` would be equivalent to `S_im(&s, whatever);`.  Note that operations on a structure-type variable will operate on the variable itself, unlike operations on a class-type variable which (as with C's `->` token) will be performed upon something to which the variable holds a reference.

PS--I dislike the decision to have C# use `.` rather than `->` for class field access or for the invocation of class member functions by passing the object reference contained in a variable.  I would rather have seen `foo.whatever` consistently refer to or modify `foo` itself, and `foo->whatever` consistently refer to or modify a thing to which `foo` holds a reference.  Even with class objects, non-virtual methods could have been implemented to pass a byref to the variable, such that e.g. `someString.Append(x);` would have been equivalent to `String_Append(ref x);` and could change what the variable `someString` holds (e.g. making it point to a different instance of `String`).  Too late now, though.